# How to do notifications on chrome mobile?

Tags: android, google-chrome, notifications

I want to use notifications on my android mobile phone with chrome browser. I saw this demo page

http://alexgibson.github.io/notify.js/

It seems to work fine on firefox on desktop and chrome on desktop, but if I try it on chrome on android phone, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know if this is supported on mobile?

Thanks

Comment: It's in the README.md

Browser support

Chrome (desktop)
Safari
Firefox
Firefox OS (v1.2+)
Firefox Mobile (Android)

Comment: So theres currently no working version for chrome mobile?

Comment: Why dont you ask [Alex Gibson](https://github.com/alexgibson), i'm pretty sure he'll respond to that question....